# Is it necessary to invoke setValid(true) in decode() in a JSF Custom Component?

Tags: jsf

While working with a custom component I have the problem, that `UIInput#getValid()` never resets itself. Question is: do I have to invoke `setValid(true)` myself during Apply Request Values Phase?

Here are the steps I have done:

- Create a custom component and inherit from `UIInput`
- The component invokes `setConverter` in the constructor
- The converter was designed for this component alone and throws a `ConverterException` if it can't convert from String to the model object
- There are no validators
- `decode()` is overriden, and if `FacesContext#isPostback` returns true we invoke `setSubmittedValue` with the request value
- During render response I check `isValid()`, it returns true if a `ConverterException` was thrown, and I can render the response accordingly
- **But**: If I submit another correct value the `setValid(true)` is never called for the custom component

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default implementation of `UIInput#decode()` indeed calls `EditableValueHolder#setValid()` with `true`.

So you have 2 options:

- Simply invoke `super.decode(context)` in your `UIInput#decode()` instead of manually grabbing submitted value and invoking `setSubmittedValue()` with it (because that's already the default behavior of `UIInput#decode()`).
- Or, manually invoke `setValid(true)` in your `UIInput#decode()` before invoking `setSubimttedValue()`.